# Is there any way to embed a VSTO add-in into a document?

Tags: vsto, office-interop, office-addins

At this moment, I have a VSTO add-in fulfilling my requirement. But it needs to run with Visual Studio or installed. Ideally, I want to have a Word file containing this VSTO add-in and put this file on my server so that user can use my add-in just by downloading this file, no need to any extra work. Is it possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [How to: Publish a ClickOnce application using the Publish Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-publish-a-clickonce-application-using-the-publish-wizard?view=vs-2019)

Comment: As far as I understand, it needs installation as well. I want to inject my add-in into a docx file, usable just by opening that file without any installation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VSTO project *must* be installed, whether it's an add-in or a document-level customization. Installation ensures that the correct version of the .NET Framework and other pre-requisites are installed. It also includes the user explicitly *trusting* the solution.

If you want something that distributes with a document then you need VBA, embedded in the document and saved as a *.docm file. Note that this file type will trigger macro security - some people will have settings that won't allow VBA to run. Some will have settings that can allow "trusted" and/or signed projects to run (you can research that).